# Linking problem of weak functions in stm32 using CMake

Tags: c, cmake, stm32

Environment:

- Win10
- STM32CubeMX 6.8.1
- Clion 2022.3.2
- gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3
- CMake 3.26.1

Hello. I am trying the freertos in stm32.

I enabled freertos in cubemx, then change the default task to `TaskMain` and ask it to generate the start function "as weak".

I add all the code that CubeMX generated to a library target. And I add another `main.cpp` to an executable target as user codes and link to the library target.

In my `main.cpp`, I redefined the weak function.

```cpp
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "gpio.h"

void TaskMain(void* args) {
    UNUSED(args);
    while (true) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        osDelay(1000);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        osDelay(1000);
    }
}
```

But the program will not run into the `TaskMain` function in `main.cpp`. It stucks in the endless loop in the weak function in`freertos.c`.

Someone said that cut the declaration of the function in `freertos.c` and paste it into `main.h` under `Exported functions prototypes` and include `main.h` in `main.cpp` could soulve the problem. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does name mangling. The most frequent place to run into similar problem on STM32 is with IRQ handlers. If you have a weak while(1) IRQ handler in .c, and you define another IRQ handler with the same name in .cpp, it will not work, because on the linking stage the names of the weak and "strong" function are not the same anymore. Your situation seems similar.

The solution is to force a function not to have a mangled name.

```
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "gpio.h"


void TaskMain(void* args) asm("TaskMain");
void TaskMain(void* args) {
    UNUSED(args);
    while (true) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        osDelay(1000);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        osDelay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd expect `extern "C" void TaskMain(void  * args);`